# Twilio Studio API and updating the function_sid between accounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When using the new Studio API to import and export Studio flow JSON everything transfers correctly, however when importing from another account there are issues translating functions.

The service and environment sid can be replaced for the entire flow. While not ideal the process could however be automated. The real problem is with the function sid .Finding the function_sid would need to be manual or an api call to retrieve making this a more complicated process.

Currently the other option is to open the flow in the UI and mannual select the correct function. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is an example of the area of JSON that is an issue.

```
"properties": {
    "service_sid": "<Your-service-sid-unique-to-account>",
    "environment_sid": "<Your-environment-sid-unique-to-account/service>",
    "offset": {
      "x": -1230,
      "y": -7330
    },
    "function_sid": "<Your-function-sid-unique-to-function>",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "value": "{{trigger.message.From}}",
        "key": "from"
      }
    ],
    "url": "https://<function-endpoint>.twil.io/data/<function>"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of my collegues:

I would set the FQDN of the Twilio Function using liquid syntax in the [Run Function Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function), that way the customer only has to update their [Set Variables Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables) in the case of having multiple function calls

Comment: I am still a little confused. Setting the FQDN isn't as much the issue as the SIDs for service, environment, and function. Certainly the service and environment are potentially static for the entire flow and the FQDN can use the liquid, but the function SID is unique per function. I am looking to not have to touch say 16 to 20 widgets every time we publish to QC. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's what currently exists.

Comment: Well at least now I am certain I am doing the best I can. Thank you sir.

Comment: I wanted to come back and add this is exactly what I was looking for. I should be noted that you need to ignore the widgets UI for the functions as they will ignore the service, environment, and function sids. These seemingly are only used to build the FQDN. Using the variable and setting it only once per deployment. Works perfectly.